# Isotope one per row limit

Tags: css, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

I am using isotope masonry.
Everything is looking fine but the fact that isotope is starting to display one image per row on 1000px. 
I would like to have it display 1 image per row starting 400px and below.
Is there a setting in isotope for that?

Answer (score 0):

Some example code would help in this issue, however, with that being said are you using a grid-sizer'/element-sizer in your code? if you are this is possible with media queries.
Eample from docs:

JS

```
masonry: {
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
}
```

CSS

```
/* 3 columns by default */
.grid-sizer { width: 33.333%; }

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* 5 columns for larger screens */
    .grid-sizer { width: 20%; }
}
```

see: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html#element-sizing